# What MIME type should I use for CSV?

Tags: csv, http-headers, mime-types, content-type

I've seen `application/csv` used and also `text/csv`.

Is there a difference?  Does it matter which as long as the request matches something that's available?  Are they interchangeable?

Comment: For those who are in doubt regarding Media Types, I leave here this document from IANA which provides a list of registered Media Types: https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Answer (score 799, accepted):

#### RFC 7111

There is an [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7111) which covers it and says to use `text/csv`.

This RFC updates RFC 4180.

#### Excel

Recently I discovered an explicit mimetype for Excel application/vnd.ms-excel. It was registered with [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.ms-excel) in '96. Note the concerns raised about being at the *mercy of the sender* and *having your machine violated*.

> #### Media Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
>
> Name             Microsoft Excel (tm)
>
> Required parameters:      None
>
> Optional parameters:      name
>
> Encoding considerations:  base64 preferred
>
> Security considerations:  As with most application types this data is
> intended for interpretation by a program that understands the data on
> the recipient's system. Recipients need to understand that they are at
> the "mercy" of the sender, when receiving this type of data, since
> data will be executed on their system, and the security of their
> machines can be violated.
>
> OID              { org-id ms-files(4) ms-excel (3) }
>
> Object type      spreadsheet
>
> Comments         This Media Type/OID is used to identify Microsoft
> Excel generically (i.e., independent of version, subtype, or platform format).

I wasn't aware that vendor extensions were allowed. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351093/what-is-the-meaning-of-vnd-in-mime-types/5351162) to find out more - thanks [starbeamrainbowlabs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1460422/starbeamrainbowlabs) for the reference.

Comment: CSV is a text file format, why would Excel have anything to do with it, or am I missing something?

Comment: If you have installed excel on Mac OS the .csv filetype is bound to excel unless you change it.

Comment: That a program opens a file type doesn't have anything to do with the associated MIME type of that file type.

Comment: @Pablo, nobody said it did.  I said there's an entry for Excel in the mimetypes database - odd but ok I think.  Rutger separately said that .csv opens in Excel on Mac (if installed).

Comment: @Pablo I have Excel installed on a Windows machine, and creating a CSV in Notepad++ will assign a MIME type of application/vnd.ms-excel. Try it for yourself and check your MIME type at http://mime.ritey.com/

Comment: Notepad++ doesnt "assign" any mime type, the service you use is assigning it.

Comment: @pjd - Pablo's correct, Notepad doesn't assign the MIME type - actually the service doesn't assign it either though as it is done by the "Network Working Group" mentioned in the RFC

Comment: @Pablo and Chris McCauley: Good to know. Interesting that I am seeing different MIME types on different computers, though. A Linux box vs a Windows box with Excel installed.

Comment: It's really down to whatever is in /etc/mime.types on Linux - not sure how Windows manages it.

Comment: Windows manages its list of mimetypes in the registry at `HKLM\Software\Classes` - the `Content Type` defined for the .csv entry when Excel is configured as the default application to handle them is `application/vnd.ms-excel` and so this is the value passed in.

Comment: @Nuno - that's why I didn't link the "text/csv" mime type to Excel in my answer but pointed out that there is a specific mime type to use if you really are sending an Excel worksheet.

Comment: @ChrisMcCauley The CSV is a format specification, it does not tell which application will open it. The mimetype should be "text/CSV" and the user's system should open the file with this mimetype with the appropriate application (eg: excel, notepad++, etc). It is a workaround or a decision you make to force it to open the file using excel. Kind regards.

Comment: @NunoAniceto,  I'm not saying that it does.  I'm answering the OPs question and observing that there's an additional MIME type which will be of interest to Excel users.

Comment: For those curious as to what the `vnd` stands for in this answer, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351093/what-is-the-meaning-of-vnd-in-mime-types/5351162)

Comment: the link to the mimetype database shows no info pn text/csv nor application/csv...

Comment: @Henning, Thanks I've updated the post to point to a better source and quoted the relevant parts.

Comment: It's not about being butt-hurt, but about 80 percent of the answer being, in fact, off-topic.

Comment: @StijndeWitt  The first line directly answers the question asked.  The rest is as others have said, is interesting.  That's not surprising given how many folks use Excel to open CSV files.

Comment: As someone who found this answer from a Google search because of a random UI validation error, this answer was hugely relevant.

Comment: interestingly I had a script setup for 'application/vnd.ms-excel' (for 2-3 years) - but today I had to add text/csv as an alternative because the csv (edited in Excel as normal - the colleague says) did not have the mime-type of 'application/vnd.ms-excel' - has something changed recently?

Comment: @UrbanwarfareStudios  Not sure if it helps but there's an earlier comment that says  "Windows manages its list of mimetypes in the registry at HKLM\Software\Classes - the Content Type defined for the .csv entry when Excel is configured as the default application to handle them is application/vnd.ms-excel and so this is the value passed in. – 
Zhaph - Ben Duguid
 Sep 24, 2015 at 14:15"

Answer (score 125):

You should use "text/csv" according to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

Comment: Does "text/csv" accept ".txt" files as well? I am working on applying validation on server side to just accept ".csv" file types. But the ".txt" files also get accepted.Please confirm.

Comment: sorry but havn't seen your question so far. RFC 4180 makes sure that the extension should be .csv. Nevertheless a you might know, it's not a strict requirement. You can break the implementation of the RFC 4180, but personally I would not do that, because it is disturbing the readability of the application.

Comment: Files edited with Excel will show up as `application/vnd.ms-excel`

Answer (score 60):

Strange behavior with `MS Excel`:
If i export to "text based, comma-separated format (`csv`)" this is the mime-type I get after uploading on my webserver:

```
[name] => data.csv
[type] => application/vnd.ms-excel
```

So Microsoft seems to be doing own things again, regardless of existing standards: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: You cant really trust the mime-type sent by web clients, its just a guide generally.

Comment: This is due to the configuration of the web-server which maps file extension to mime type. Microsofts IIS should use the servers registry for this which is populated by the Excel installation if it is installed on the web server.

Comment: Well...Considering that the "existing standard" decided to ignore what was already in use when they decided to define CSV in RFC 4180 which was written in October of 2005, it would be silly to blame Microsoft for not jumping into the future to see what the standards body decides and then use that back when they first wrote excel back in 1985.  What version of excel are you installing?

Comment: On top of everything else, excel will mangle the field values in a CSV file.

Comment: maybe, it depends what "after uploading" actually means.

Comment: @ChrisSeufert For structured "text" based files, like CSVs, the only way yo validate is to check the columns. For "binary" files, checking the signature of the file before storing it.

Answer (score 60):

My users are allowed to upload CSV files and `text/csv` and `application/csv` did not appear by now. These are the ones identified through [finfo()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23287361/318765):

```
text/plain
text/x-csv
```

And these are the ones transmitted through the browser:

```
text/plain
application/vnd.ms-excel
text/x-csv
```

The following types did not appear, but could:

```
application/csv
application/x-csv
text/csv
text/comma-separated-values
text/x-comma-separated-values
text/tab-separated-values
```

Comment: Browsers guess what to send as the MIME type of a file during upload. You can reject out of hand ones you want nothing to do with, but checking the actual content of the file with care is the only way to be sure what's been uploaded.

Comment: text/tab-separated-values is technically not CSV file; or do you mean you can also get it even for comma separated data?

Comment: @Arthur Feel free to use an additional TSV file category. I ignore the other terms because many programs create a file with the .csv extension no matter which delimiter is used and PHP - as the most used server-side language-  uses the term CSV in it's functions only, too. Call it "character separated files" and you're fine ;)

Answer (score 18):

For anyone struggling with Google API mimeType for `*.csv` files, I have found the list of MIME types for google api docs files

| Google Doc Format | Conversion Format | Corresponding MIME type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Documents | HTML | `text/html` |
|  | HTML (zipped) | `application/zip` |
|  | Plain text | `text/plain` |
|  | Rich text | `application/rtf` |
|  | Open Office doc | `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text` |
|  | PDF | `application/pdf` |
|  | MS Word document | `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` |
|  | EPUB | `application/epub+zip` |
| Spreadsheets | MS Excel | `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` |
|  | Open Office sheet | `application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet` |
|  | PDF | `application/pdf` |
|  | CSV (first sheet only) | `text/csv` |
|  | TSV (first sheet only) | `text/tab-separated-values` |
|  | HTML (zipped) | `application/zip` |
| Drawings | JPEG | `image/jpeg` |
|  | PNG | `image/png` |
|  | SVG | `image/svg+xml` |
|  | PDF | `application/pdf` |
| Presentations | MS PowerPoint | `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation` |
|  | Open Office presentation | `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation` |
|  | PDF | `application/pdf` |
|  | Plain text | `text/plain` |
| Apps Scripts | JSON | `application/vnd.google-apps.script+json` |

Source here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents
the table under:
"Google Doc formats and supported export MIME types map to each other as follows"

There is also another list

| MIME Type | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.audio` |  |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.document` | Google Docs |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.drawing` | Google Drawing |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.file` | Google Drive file |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` | Google Drive folder |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.form` | Google Forms |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.fusiontable` | Google Fusion Tables |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.map` | Google My Maps |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.photo` |  |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.presentation` | Google Slides |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.script` | Google Apps Scripts |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.site` | Google Sites |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` | Google Sheets |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.unknown` |  |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.video` |  |
| `application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk` | 3rd party shortcut |

Source here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types

But the first one was more helpful for my use case.

Comment: Plus one because of the pretty formatted tables  :)

Comment: Here is another list from mozilla.org https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types to refer doubts regarding mime types.