# Rails paperclip file validation - file type Microsoft text/csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, paperclip

I am using paperclip to upload CSV files. I need to validate them, that only CSV files can be uploaded:

```
validates_attachment :uploaded_file_csv, content_type: { content_type: ['text/csv']} , message: "is not in CSV format"
```

But I have a problem with this validator: If user uploading file from Windows operation system or file was created by using Microsoft Office - this validator rising error that file is invalid. 
How to validate microsoft/csv files?

Answer (score 0):

Add in the following content_type:  application/vnd.ms-excel

> The MIME type application/vnd.ms-excel is used to denote the presence of a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet or Microsoft Excel template. The category for this MIME type is "application". You should use "text/csv" according to RFC 4180.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076042/what-mime-type-should-i-use-for-csv)