# Generating excel using jsp

Tags: excel, jsp

I am trying to generate excel using JSP, but generated file is not getting opened directly. If I save this file and try to open then it is getting opened but if I try to open it directly then getting below error:

> The file is corrupt and cannot be opened.

I am using below specification for response header:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+"fileName.xls");
```

I also tried:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you really generating an xls file (binary proprietary format from Microsoft) using JSP, or simply a Comma Separated Values file?

Comment: I am trying to generate excel file and jsf is used to format data in row and column format for excel.

Comment: Data formatted in row and column is **not** in excel format but in CSV. In that case you should declare `response.setContentType("text/csv");` as explained in that [other SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7076079/3545273)

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I tried using content type as "text/csv" but it is not working. Still same issue.

Comment: Did you associate this file extension in your browser to be opened with the right application?

Comment: No, I am not associating this file extension in browser. Extension is concatenated with file name. Since extension is .xls so it should open in excel file. Also table format is being used to represent data.

Comment: If its is a csv file, use `.csv` as extension... `.xls` is a different format.