# Set a mimetype for a csv file

Tags: symfony, csv, mime-types

I am working on preexisting code which allows users to import csv files. I am trying to understand how the code works with some csv files but it fails at this condition:

```php
if ($data['file']->getClientMimeType() == 'application/vnd.ms-excel') {
```

How can I set the mimetype of my csv file? How do I access the header of my csv file to set it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What MIME type should I use for CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076042/what-mime-type-should-i-use-for-csv)

Comment: You must set it not for file, but for request. (at least I think so)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understading Please try to implement this..

```
   getClientMimeType() == 'text/csv'
```

Also You can also check All/Specific type of mime types from this link(If you need any).

```
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types
```