# What mime type should I use for CSV ZIP files?

Tags: mime-types

I am trying to send an email using Simple Java Mail API. The email will contain a CSV ZIP file attachment. Should I use `text/csv` or `application/zip` for the mime type of the attachment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What MIME type should I use for CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076042/what-mime-type-should-i-use-for-csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A zip file is a zip file, no matter what it contains.

It should be `application/zip`.

It is not a CSV file, if you tried to parse it as CSV it would fail. It is not `text/csv`.

Answer (score 0):

In linux, you can find way much of the in the following file: `/etc/mime.types`.
See below to find out what mime is suitable for `zip` files.

```
grep zip /etc/mime.types

application/bacnet-xdd+zip                      xdd
application/epub+zip                            epub
application/gzip                                gz tgz
application/lpf+zip                             lpf
application/prs.hpub+zip                        hpub
application/tlsrpt+gzip
application/vnd.airzip.filesecure.azf           azf
application/vnd.airzip.filesecure.azs           azs
application/vnd.comicbook+zip                   cbz
application/vnd.d2l.coursepackage1p0+zip
application/vnd.dece.zip                        uvz uvvz
application/vnd.espass-espass+zip               espass
application/vnd.etsi.asic-e+zip                 asice sce
application/vnd.etsi.asic-s+zip                 asics
application/vnd.exstream-empower+zip            mpw
application/vnd.ficlab.flb+zip                  flb
application/vnd.gov.sk.e-form+zip
application/vnd.imagemeter.folder+zip           imf
application/vnd.imagemeter.image+zip            imi
application/vnd.iso11783-10+zip
application/vnd.laszip
application/vnd.logipipe.circuit+zip            lcs lca
application/vnd.software602.filler.form-xml-zip zfo
application/vnd.stepmania.package               smzip
application/zip                                 zip
image/vnd.airzip.accelerator.azv                azv
model/vnd.usdz+zip                              usdz
application/x-bzip2                             bz2
```