# Unable to download file: Could not find acceptable representation

Tags: java, spring-boot

This has tons of example on the internet but for some reason I just cannot download a csv file. I keep getting the error:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation`.
```

Here is the code below for my `@RestController`:

```
      @GetMapping(value = "/tasks/{taskId}/download", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
      public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> download(@PathVariable String taskId, @RequestParam String format) throws IOException {

        var path = "string path to file"

        var file = new UrlResource(Path.of(path).normalize().toUri());
        return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentLength(file.contentLength())
            .contentType(
                MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
            .body(new InputStreamResource(file.getInputStream()));
      }
```

I set the header `Accept: application/octet-stream` but still get the same error. What could be wrong any ideas?

Comment: The [mime type for csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076042/what-mime-type-should-i-use-for-csv) is typically `text/csv`, why are you using `application/octet-stream`?

Comment: Just to be in the ballpark. I thought it wouldnt matter in this case. Does it?

Comment: what does your rest call look like

Comment: and i think you dont have to set the contentType if you have set produces