# Automatically downloading .csv in Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have the following code:

```
element_search_field = browser.find_element_by_id(search_field_id)
op.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
op.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
op.set_preference("browser.download.dir","C:\\Users\\user\\Selenium")
op.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream,application/vnd.csv")

downloadcsv =  browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#downloadOCTable')
downloadcsv.click();
```

I am having trouble at the last line `downloadcsv.click();`. I was hoping that changing `"application/octet-stream,application/vnd.csv")` from `"application/octet-stream,application/vnd.ms-excel")` would automatically save the .csv file to the downloads folder but i am still get the DialogBox. Is there anyway I can have it saved without the DiaglogBox?

Edit:

As suggested by @Prophet:

I had made these changes but i am still get the pop up

profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", userAgent)

```
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Users\\[user]\\Selenium Options")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/csv,application/excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.msexcel,text/anytext,text/comma-separated-values,text/csv,text/plain,text/x-csv,application/x-csv,text/x-comma-separated-values,text/tab-separated-values,data:text/csv")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/xml,text/plain,text/xml,image/jpeg,application/octet-stream,data:text/csv")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/csv,application/excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.msexcel,text/anytext,text/comma-separated-values,text/csv,text/plain,text/x-csv,application/x-csv,text/x-comma-separated-values,text/tab-separated-values,data:text/csv")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/xml,text/plain,text/xml,image/jpeg,application/octet-stream,data:text/csv")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
profile.set_preference("dom.file.createInChild", True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several kinds of `csv` applications. We can't know what will work for the specific site you are working with.
I have all these preferences set and so far it works for me in all the cases

```py
op.set_preference("browser.download.dir", downloadsPath)
op.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/csv,application/excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.msexcel,text/anytext,text/comma-separated-values,text/csv,text/plain,text/x-csv,application/x-csv,text/x-comma-separated-values,text/tab-separated-values,data:text/csv")
op.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/xml,text/plain,text/xml,image/jpeg,application/octet-stream,data:text/csv")
op.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
op.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
op.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/csv,application/excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.msexcel,text/anytext,text/comma-separated-values,text/csv,text/plain,text/x-csv,application/x-csv,text/x-comma-separated-values,text/tab-separated-values,data:text/csv")
op.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/xml,text/plain,text/xml,image/jpeg,application/octet-stream,data:text/csv")
op.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
op.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
op.set_preference("dom.file.createInChild", True)
```

`downloadsPath` here is a path to Downloads folder

Answer (score 0):

You should use the MIME type for .csv as `text/csv`, you can check [rfc4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#page-4)

The below following type could help you

```
application/csv
application/x-csv
text/csv
text/comma-separated-values
text/x-comma-separated-values
text/tab-separated-values
text/plain
text/x-csv
```

So you can check it as below

```
op.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv,application/octet-stream")
```

[here is a great discussion happens you can check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076042/what-mime-type-should-i-use-for-csv)