# What is the mimeType attribute in <data> used for?

Tags: android, mime-types

I really can’t get the meaning of mimeType. I know that it exists so that the `getType` method in `ContentProvider` knows what to match with it. But I’m still not sure what it means or how it’s used.

Comment: @Randroid If there was a downvote for comments.......

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Any `ContentProvider` usually defines the type of data it handles (e.g. [NotePadProvider](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NotePadProvider.html) handles a `Notes` data type  defined in an inner class of [NotePad](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NotePad.html)). A MIME type is just a standardized way to define that data type by giving it a unique name. This allows the data type to be communicated to code that works with a `ContentProvider` in a standardized way.

It also helps a `ContentProvider` that handles several different types of data to keep things organized, e.g. a `RailwayContentProvider` might handle trains, stations and tickets and can use the MIME type to tell each one apart.

**Why MIME types?**

The use of MIME types is a natural consequence when you think about how a `ContentProvider` is accessed through URIs, i.e. something like an URL on the Internet. Just like on the Internet there are MIME types like `text/html` for web pages and `image/jpeg` for .jpg images, Android wants you to define a custom MIME type for any data type your `ContentProvider` handles.

**An example custom MIME type**

In the NotePad (linked above) class of the NotePad example project, you'll find:

```
public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.google.note";
```

This field defines a custom MIME type (recognizable by the `type/subtype` pattern).

Android suggests you use `vnd.android.cursor.dir/...` as the first part for any kind of "directory listing" (multiple items) and `vnd.android.cursor.item/...` as the first part for any kind of single item.

For the subtype, it's again suggested to start it with `vnd.` and then add something like your reverse domain name/package name, e.g. `vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.mydomain.myapp.mydata`

To avoid all those `vnd...` strings in your code, there's also some constants in `ContentResolver` like [CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE) and [CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE).

Comment: I highly recommend the [NotePad example project](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html) if you want to write your own `ContentProvider` (posting as comment due to link limit in answer).

Comment: Wonderful answer!!!!
So we can put anything we like behind "vnd.android.cursor.dir/",right?Or it has some constraint that must be follow to avoid conflict with exist mimeTypes?

Comment: The Android docs suggest you also start the subtype (after the `/`) with `vnd.` to mark it as "custom MIME subtype" [see: What is the meaning of "vnd" in MIME types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351093/what-is-the-meaning-of-vnd-in-mime-types) -- after that just use reverse-domain notation (i.e. Java package names) to get a unique name. See the last the last paragraph of my answers for an example :)

Comment: To avoid all those `vnd...` strings in your code, there's also some constants in `ContentResolver` like [CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE) and [CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE).

Comment: @Philipp Reichart : great answer, thanks, it should be as clear as you answer in the doc!

Comment: if anyone is still unclear on this i highly recommend this article : http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-content-provider-basics/

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.

Answer (score 12):

Mimetype **Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions** is tell you the description of the content

Text in character sets other than ASCII

Non-text attachments

Message bodies with multiple parts

Header information in non-ASCII character sets

and also whether is it Pdf/epub/html/text etc

Answer (score 3):

If you mean mime type its to tell the receiving entity how to interpret a file. Just like you see .txt and know a file is a text file. This way you can serve a file with .anyExtension and have the browser still know it is a .txt

Comment: Regretfull, in android it does not mean file type.